# How to run .bat file on Heroku? (trying to set up discord music bot on Heroku)

Tags: python, batch-file, heroku, discord

I have been trying to host a discord bot on Heroku.
Bot link: 
https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot

I have set it all up and successfully host it on my own computer.
The problem is that I want to host it on an online service like Heroku.
Successfully deploy and it said found a python app.
However I didn't see the bot in discord goes online...

This is what I think the problem is, 
when I host it on my computer I have to run "runbot.bat" file
which looks like this:

```
@ECHO off

CHCP 65001 > NUL
CD /d "%~dp0"

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET KEY_NAME="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
SET VALUE_NAME=HideFileExt

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    SET ValueName=%%A
    SET ValueType=%%B
    SET ValueValue=%%C
)

IF x%ValueValue:0x0=%==x%ValueValue% (
    ECHO Unhiding file extensions...
    START CMD /c REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
)
ENDLOCAL


IF EXIST %SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe (
    CMD /k py.exe -3.5 run.py
    EXIT
)

python --version > NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO nopython

CMD /k python run.py
GOTO end

:nopython
ECHO ERROR: Python has either not been installed or not added to your PATH.

:end
PAUSE
```

And there's a file called "procfile" which I learned from here: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5dkqpd/help_how_do_you_host_a_discord_bot_from_heroku/

I have tried

```
worker: runboot.bat
```

,

```
worker: python run.py
```

and

```
worker: python bot.py
```

but no luck. I think the process type is missing or wrong for the .bat file.
How do I run .bat file on Heroku? 
Or if anyone has some experience of hosting this bot, any help would be really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure Heroku stuff doesn't run on Windows usually

Comment: Heroku doesn't run the things you out there on Windows. Of course you can command it from a Commodore 64 if you like. Still it doesn't run Windows bats for you

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs Linux. So, it's just technically impposible to run batch file (as well as `ffmpeg.exe` from that github repo).

> `A dyno is a lightweight Linux container that runs a single user-specified command.` said the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos).

So try some Linux-compatible programs instead.

p.s. run `heroku logs` for detailed info about why your app couldn't work.